# AWS lambda - Not working when calling and called lambda functions inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My calling and called lambda functions are inside the same VPC. When I invoke the lambda function from another lambda function , it results in
"Task timed out after 123.09 seconds". But without VPC the function is working fine.

Can anyone help how can I resolve this.

Comment: Please provide example code, will your question may ch easier to understand and answer

Comment: Share the lambda VPC configurations. Lambda function should be in private subnet with internet access if in VPC, to be able to call other lambda functions. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

Answer (score 0):

My lambda function working well with VPC.

The steps to configure lambda inside VPC is found in below link.

https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12